A/B Multivariant testing gives 500 error in Web Database but works in Master Database
Sitecore Version: 10.2.2
We have started AB testing in our application. We were able to set Page level AB testing and we were trying for component level AB testing and Multivariant testing. Once we start the test the page doesn't come up on web.
We are getting the following error in our CD servers,
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.ComponentTesting.TestVariationSelector.GetTestValueItem(Language language) +107
   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.SelectVariation.Evaluate(CustomizeRenderingArgs args) +281
   (Object , Object ) +13
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1267
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +235
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +194
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +160
   Sitecore.Personalization.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetRenderer.CustomizeRendering.Process(GetRendererArgs args) +365
   (Object , Object ) +13
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1267
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +235
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +194
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +160
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.GetRenderer() +335
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering.get_Renderer() +30
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.CreateCyclePreventer(String placeholderName, Rendering rendering) +90
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +162
   (Object , Object ) +13
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1267
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +235
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +194
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +249
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +60
   ASP._Page_Views__Layout__Global_cshtml.Execute() in D:\CD1\Views\_Layout\_Global.cshtml:114
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +251
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +147
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +121
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) +135
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +262

[InvalidOperationException: Error while rendering view: '/Views/_Layout/_Global.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').
]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer) +735
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +297
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39

Also noticed that the Test variations counts are not showing in "Web" database's final layout and only visible in "master" database final layout.

We tried the following,

I have made sure that everything is published and available in web
database.

Goals are deployed.

Workflow has been removed to create the test.

Made sure these three settings are enabled in Sitecore.config on the
Content Delivery server: xDB.Enabled,xDB.Tracking.Enabled and ContentTesting.Enabled.

Made sure the test definition item, is    located in the folder
/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab, and have the
workflow state Deployed and published to the Web database too.



Try selecting Publish All Related Items. (Make sure all related items, including components, test variations, and layouts, are published from the master database to the web database.)

Hi Ajay, we already published all the items and it's related items. Ensured that everything in is web db. Only the test variation count I referred in image is not showing in web final layout

You most likely have an out of sync between master and web database for corresponding page.
I suggest to inspect Final renderings field under Layout section with Raw values turned on under VIEW ribbon.

The discrepancy of both master and web database should reflect underlying issue and it should be resolved after republishing the item with exact language and version.
Remarks: s:mvt attribute serves as a reference of Multivariate Test Variable which stored under /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab/.
